# how to make input fields editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/195/) which is having user tab.In user tab ,there are three fields which accepts name,mobile and email.When a user fills all the three and hits add button then a row is inserted.Now i want to make the new added row editable.This means that I want to keep 2 bootstrap buttons edit and delete.So if delete is pressed then the entire row will be deleted and if edit is pressed then the entire will be editable where user can change the mobile number,name and email.Can any body please tell me how to do.
This js code adds new rows

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(".span4").val() != "") {
            $("#mytable").append('<tr id="mytr' + val + '"></tr>');
            $tr=$("#mytr" + val);
            $tr.append('<td class=\"cb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"yes\" name="mytr' + val + '" unchecked ></td>');
            $(".span4").each(function () {
                $tr.append("<td >" + $(this).val() + "</td>");
            });
            var arr={};
            name=($tr.find('td:eq(1)').text());
            email=($tr.find('td:eq(2)').text());
            mobile=($tr.find('td:eq(3)').text());
            arr['name']=name;arr['email']=email;arr['mobile']=mobile;
            obj[val]=arr;
            val++;
        } else {
            alert("please fill the form completely");
        }
```

Comment: Have you added the add/delete buttons?

Comment: no i have not.Adding button is not a big task.i need the functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is so specific to the OP scenario, so i will try to make the answer a bit more general.

I'm no expert here, but it seems you already capture the user's input and cloned it when they click Add to a new td. Therefore from what I understood is that you need to edit/delete the data from the new created td.

We have a table that contains several fields. We want to apply the following action on them

1- Add

2- Edit

3- Delete

Maybe this isn't the best practice, in short, my approach for this was to insert two spans for each data value:

- One hidden that contains an input text field (inputSpan).
- Another just contains plain text value (dataSpan).

Whenever you want to edit, dataSpan (just a data container) will disappear and inputSpan (text input field) appears instead enabling you to edit the text field. Once you edit and click Save the data in the text field will be cloned to replace the data in dataSpan. So basically dataSpan is just a reflection to inputSpan text field.

Here is an updated demo:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjoraid/6gJX4/66/) >> [FullView Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjoraid/6gJX4/66/embedded/result/)

I suggest for readability purposes, you break your code down into small function, it will make life easier, just sayin. So here general logic for your idea:

```
   deleteRow = function (trID) {
        // delete code goes here, remove the row
        $(trID).remove();
    }

manageEdit = function (tdNo) {
    if ($("#edit-btn" + tdNo).html() === "Edit") { 
        $("#save-btn" + tdNo).show();//show save button
        $("#edit-btn" + tdNo).html("Cancel");//change edit to cancle
        editRow(tdNo);//call edit function
    } else if ($("#edit-btn" + tdNo).html() === "Cancel") { 
        $("#save-btn" + tdNo).hide();//hide save button
        $("#edit-btn" + tdNo).html("Edit");//change back edit button to edit
        cancelEditRow(tdNo);
    }
}

editRow = function (tdNo) {
    $(".inputSpan" + tdNo).show();//show text input fields
    $(".dataSpan" + tdNo).hide();//hide data display
}

cancelEditRow = function (tdNo) { 
    //looop thru 3 input fields by id last digit
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //get input span that contain the text field
        var inputSpan = $("#inputSpan" + tdNo + "-" + i);
        //get the data span that contain the display data
        var dataSpan = $("#dataSpan" + tdNo + "-" + i);
        //text field inside inputSpan
        var textField = inputSpan.find('input:text');
        inputSpan.hide();//hide input span
        textField.val(dataSpan.html());//take original data from display span and put it inside text field to cncle changes. 
        dataSpan.show();//show data span instead of edit field
    }
}

saveRow = function (tdNo) { 
    //same as edit, but we reverse the data selection. 
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var inputSpan = $("#inputSpan" + tdNo + "-" + i);
        var dataSpan = $("#dataSpan" + tdNo + "-" + i);
        var textField = inputSpan.find('input:text');
        inputSpan.hide();
        dataSpan.html(textField.val());//take data from text field and put into dataSpan
        dataSpan.show();

    }
    $("#edit-btn" + tdNo).html("Edit");//change text to edit
    $("#save-btn" + tdNo).hide();//hide same button. 
}
```

Here where I add the spans:

```
     var tdCounter = 0;             
      $(".span4").each(function () { 
           var tid =  val+"-"+tdCounter;  
          $tr.append("<td id='#mytd"+tid+"'>
<span id='inputSpan"+tid+"' class='inputSpan"+val+"' style='display:none'>
<input type='text' id='#input"+tid+"' value='"+ $(this).val() + "' /></span>
<span id='dataSpan"+tid+"'  class='dataSpan"+val+"'>"+$(this).val()+"</td>");               
          tdCounter++;              
                });
```

Here I just append the buttons to call the functions, each button works for it's own row:

```
   $tr.append("<td><botton id='edit-btn" + val + "' class='btn' onclick=manageEdit('" + val + "');>Edit</botton></td>");
   $tr.append("<td><botton style='display:none' id='save-btn" + val + "' class='btn' onclick=saveRow('" + val + "');>Save</botton></td>");
   $tr.append("<td><botton id='delete-btn" + val + "' class='btn' onclick=deleteRow('" + trID + "');>Delete</botton></td>");
```

Comment: Friend yesterday I did not see your answer properly just gave you +1 as you have provided Fiddle But today when I checked,the edit button is not working

Comment: Yup true, no worries. I will check it now.

Comment: Check it now I updated the answer and improved the solutions.But wondering how are you going to implement the Save? you will do it separately for each row or all at once?

Comment: Edit button is not visible

Comment: Fiddle link wasn't update :( it's updated now :) if for some reason you can't see the buttons, try to zoom out. fiddle panel is quite small.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.your edit is working now.Well after i press the edit button 2 buttons I need save and cancel.So when I press the edit button then input fields are made editable.I changed mobile number and when i press the the save button then it will display the new mobile number.Do you know how to do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40710/discussion-between-mohammed-joraid-and-javabeginner)

Comment: I added Cancel option, and only made Save to view after you click Edit. http://jsfiddle.net/mjoraid/6gJX4/61/

Comment: So far I think your question has been answered. If so, please mark the right answer as your solutions by ticking the green mark under the voting panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample function, it wont do everyhing you need, but it shows the jquery functions and one possibility how to do it. I only enabled editing name field, and deleting. 
You would have to add other fields, + copy id data for the input.

[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/f5vAT/10/)

```
window.deleteRow = function (tar) {
    $(tar).parent().remove();
}
window.editRow = function (tar) {
    var row = $(tar).parent(),
        cells, name;
    cells = row.find("td");
    name = $(cells.get(1)).text();
    $(cells.get(1)).text('');
    $(cells.get(1)).append('<input type="text" value="' + name + '">');
}

window.saveData = function() {
    var data = {};
    data.name = "some name";//get this from your input
    data.email= "some email";//get this from your input
    data.phone= "some phone";//get this from your input

    $.get("http://yourphpsite.com", data, function(data, status) {
         //data contains your server response
         if (data.somepositiveservermessage) {
             $("#user_notification_field").text("data saved");
             $("#user_notification_field").show();

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1 for the same.Well i am using bootstrap.So can this be possible using bootstrap js

Comment: well when the edit field is clicked,there I can edit the name.Thats ok but I need to save that edited name also.So how to do that?

Comment: You use ajax calls and probably PHP, thats another story, google it, there are literally thousands of examples, and tutorials on ajax and php saving.

Comment: I can do ajax for updating in the database.But i need to show in the front end UI.So how to do that

Comment: showing the "saved" notification in front end should be much easier than ajax call, if you can do ajax, you can do that.

Comment: i mostly ajax to insert into database.In jquery ajax,I just write jsp name in URL and In DATA: give the parameter names to insert in the database

Comment: Check my answer, i edited it.
those jquery ajax calls have a third parameter, which is a function that gets called if your request was successful. 
in that function you can show whatever message you want.

i.e 
add a hidden div somewhere on the page for user notifications. and if request returns a positive response, show that message.